# VS Code not start the VM device Android

Tags: flutter, react-native, sdk, android-emulator, vscode-extensions

[image]

Hello Guys!
Help me for to fix this problem.
I not now more than make.

Android Studio is last version, SDK enable for intell devices.
The path is ok fron the VsCode extension .
I need help, please.

Update  in the SDK
Enable extension
I need only this emulator runing with flutter

Comment: can u run `flutter doctor -v` and edit in your question?

Comment: 1. Expand the error message to learn which VS Code extension gave you the error. 2. Each extension has its own channel to report issues (likely on its GitHub repo).

Answer (score -1):

just in case check if the Phone you choose in AndroidStudio (VirtualDeviceManager) - has an icon with googlePlay logo
like Pixel 4 and Pixel 3a

not sure why but i could't start other models (with VS)